# Using multi-level numbering in a form

Tags: forms, information-architecture

I have a long form that I am designing with approximately 30 fields. The form is divided into 3 expand/collapsible sections. I would like to know what the community here thinks about using multi-level numbering for the form field labels. Do you think it would support/impede usability?
I am providing an example below:
[image: numbered form field labels]

Answer (score 1):

A better solution is to create a multi-step form with a progress bar above or below the form where you present the user how much left they have to fill. This has several advantages including:

1. the user will not be overwhelmed by how much they have to fill (which is, by the way, the #1 reason why users abandon forms)
2. if something happens and the page refreshes, previous progress won't get lost